# Backend Error Code 500 with google freebase query

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, freebase

I am using the following example code available at freebase documentation.

```
import json
import urllib

api_key = open(".api_key").read()
query = 'blue bottle'
service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search'
params = {
        'query': query,
        'key': api_key
}
url = service_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params)
response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
print response

for result in response['result']:
    print result['name'] + ' (' + str(result['score']) + ')'
```

I followed the api_key registration process. However I am still getting Error 500.

```
{u'error': {u'code': 503, u'message': u'Backend Error', u'errors': [{u'domain': u'global', u'message': u'Backend Error', u'reason': u'backendError'}]}}
```

There are a lot of related posts but could not find a solution from them. Is it because of the freebase being retired? Also, what would be other options identical to freebase?

Comment: Have you looked at the firebase dashboard to set up your data sources?

Comment: @kpie what kind of data sources are available ?

Comment: FireBase is google's hosted NoSql platform. You can put whatever you want into it.